# Chinese visa in Hong Kong without hotel bookings and return flight?

Tags: visas, china, hong-kong, macau

I'm an currently in Macau and just went to the Chinese consulate to apply for a Chinese visa.

I'm on my way overland from Germany to Japan and had hoped for a dual entry visa (60 days each) to make it from Macau to the Chinese east coast to take a ferry to South Korea, then Japan and back to China. I provided a list with cities and hotels I plan to stay at while in China.

The lady at the consulate looked a bit bewildered, all she could offer me is a single entry seven day tourist (L) visa and only if I had all hotel bookings and a return flight.

Several years ago I got a Chinese visa in Hong Kong at my guest house. I just handed in my passport in the afternoon, with no itinerary, no bookings, no onward tickets. I got the visa the next morning.

Is this still possible? I guess I have to find some agencies that doesn't ask any questions. I don't want to book all my hostels and the ferry in advanced, I don't know when I will be at a particular place.

Last year I got my Chinese visa in Bishkek in Kyrgyzstan through an agency and again no questions asked.

Anybody has any recent experience with visa agencies in Hong Hong or Macao?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did some research and while it used to be possible to get this in Macau in the past, the company most people suggested: [CTS](http://www.ctshk.com/english/index.htm) does not offer this service anymore. They suggested their Hong Kong office.

I contacted a different agency in HK suggested in another post on travel.stackexchange [FBT](http://www.fbt-chinavisa.com.hk/index.html), they said they don't need hotel bookings or return flights.

Today I went to Hong Kong to their offices and indeed many travelers applied with just an application form and a password photo.

The process takes (up to) 4 working days and you have to hand in your passport.

For me that was a problem because I had to return to Macau in the evening for which I needed my passport. I knew that, so I applied with my second passport which I carry for cases like this one.

But they told me I could not use that one, because I have to apply with the same passport I entered Hong Kong with.

I went back to immigration at the ferry terminal and confirmed that I have to leave with the same passport I entered with.

So, it turns out it is not possible to apply for a Chinese visa in Hong Kong while based in Macau.

The only thing I can do is moving to HK and staying there for 4 to 5 nights while waiting for my visa.

Edit: I applied on a Monday afternoon and got the visa on Thursday 1p.m., no hotel bookings or proof of onward transportation was required. You can also pay extra for a one day express service.

Comment: I can confirm that FBT services are as described (I used it 3 times the last 3 years): no docs **except a valid HKID entry ticket** (this means you can't leave Hong-Kong while the papers are being made). If you have any question, they actually answer very quickly, and may help you with other unsuspected options if required (if you have friends in China, family, business, there are many options). Their website also have up to date news about changes that could have happened and could be of interests (change in number of days required to stay for instance as in January 2016).